# MFMailComposeViewController with multiple email clients

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

So MFMailComposeViewController are using email account from Mail.app right? what if there are more than one account configured in mail.app? Is there any way to let the user to choose account before sending?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not before sending, but when the composer appears the user can tap on the From line, and a picker will pop up with all the possible email addresses.

The default will be whatever the user set as the default in the Mail settings.